# forEach does not mutate an array that I pass in

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple `forEach` function and I'm trying to understand why, when I run it with `myArray`, it doesn't mutate the array even though I run `element*2`.

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i],i,array)
  };
}

var myArray = [1,2,3]
forEach(myArray,function(element){element*2})
console.log(myArray)///[1,2,3]
```

Comment: I don't see where you are modifying the array you pass...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign new array element value, because primitive types (like numbers in your case) are immutable, so `element * 2` does not modify `element`.

To do the job, you *should not* touch you current `forEach` implementation, because `forEach` is not supposed to return values from callback (this is not map). In this case you should do something like this:

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i], i, array);
  }
}

var myArray = [1,2,3];
forEach(myArray, function(element, i, arr) { 
  arr[i] = element * 2;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify( myArray ));
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to modify the array in the for loop, like this:

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = callback(array[i],i,array)
  };
}

var myArray = [1,2,3]
forEach(myArray,function(element){return element*2})
console.log(myArray)
```

As we were discussing in the comments, the best way would be to implement something like the map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
function map(array, callback) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    out.push(callback(array[i],i,array))
  };

  return out;
}

var myArray = [1,2,3]
var myOtherArray = map(myArray,function(element){return element*2})
console.log(myArray)
console.log(myOtherArray)
```

This way myArray is not touched, you create a new one. This is usually the best option, but sometimes you may want to modify it in place, because it is huge or for some other (good?) reason. In that case you can use the first option.

Comment: Well but this is not very good, because forEach is no longer generic in this case.

Comment: Exactly. The problem with your solution is that `forEach` is now broken, because if one uses forEach like it's usually used it will overwrite entire array: `forEach(array, function(el) { console.log(el) })`.

Comment: Anyway, let's see what OP thinks and actually needs :).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, bad answer. This [snippet] would do it though.

Anyway, in modern browsers we have `Array.forEach` to [availability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function foreach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = callback(array[i]);
//  ^ assign the new value (from the callback function)    
  };
}

var myArray = [1,2,3]
foreach( myArray, function (element){ return element * 2 } );
//                                    ^ return the new value 
document.querySelector('#result').textContent = myArray;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: probably not though, because of `element` being a primitive and only in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, explicitly assigning the variable.

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = callback(array[i])
  };
}

var myArray = [1,2,3]
forEach(myArray,function(element){return element*2})
console.log(myArray)///[1,2,3]
```